# Change the window icon on an executable

Tags: game-engine

I am wondering if and how to add your own picture here.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

On **Windows**, the icon is embedded in Blenderplayer.exe. You can either...

- [Build Blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows) yourself from source code, with the modified icon.

  or
- Replace it [after-the-fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370553/changing-the-icon-of-an-exe-file-in-windows-7) with another tool like Resource Hacker.

On **Mac OS X**, the icon file is part of the app bundle. To replace it is as simple as modifying the `blender player icon.icns` file.

Comment: Will using a tool like Resource Hacker keep the icon on the executable even when it's distributed to other computers?  (I'm loving your book, Game Development With Blender!)

Comment: @Mike Pan First question outside the blender issue and what does it mean to create code that does not bother them? will it be because it will be ???

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the answer provided above, under Windows you can also make a launcher application to start you game and run it from there.

The launcher application can then have any custom icon you want.

Just create a batch file to start the game with the command

`start path/to/game.exe`

Adjust path to actually pont to the executable, possibly using a relative path to keep it working when distributed.

Use an application like [Bat to EXE](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) or similar to compile it into an executable. That executable can then be configured to use any icon file you want through Bat to EXE configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be building Blender from the source code in windows, you can modify the `winblender.ico` from `blender\release\windows\icons` and then modify `wm_window.cc` as follows.

[image]