# Executable Icon

Tags: game-engine

I noticed that when a single runtime executable is saved from the BGE, the file has the default blender logo.  Is there anyway to change this to the logo of my game?  I looked at this question: [Change the window icon on an executable](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/change-the-window-icon-on-an-executable) but the answer wasn't very helpful for me.  If somebody could explain how to do this is a lot of detail, that would be great!

Comment: For what operating system is the executable built?

Comment: Ask on the original answer to explain in more detail. Don't create another same question.