# How to make custom logo for published bge game

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I recently published a Blender game with an executable which has a Blender logo. I would however prefer to make a custom logo. How should I do this?

Comment: do you mean the desktop icon?

Comment: By default the games exe is published with blender icon. I want to make a custom icon.

Comment: I Googled "How to change program icons in Windows" and found this: http://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/

Comment: Already answered here : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/change-the-window-icon-on-an-executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a question about Blender itself, but additionally to the answers provided in the question linked above you can also make a launcher application to start you game and run it from there.

The launcher application can then have any custom icon you want.

Just create a batch file to start the game with the command
`start path/to/game.exe`

and use some application like [Bat to EXE](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) to compile it into an executable. That executable can then have any icon file you want